# New to Python, should I be using class functions for this code?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python, to be honest I was never into coding but It has come to it where I need to write some scripts, following is my script, I did pick some from here and there and finally made it to work, should I be using class and functions with this current code to make it look more professional and optimal? can someone help me to identify what is done wrong here?

```
import csv,subprocess,paramiko,time,socket
from datetime import date
IP = {}
Type = {}
Host = {}
Username = {}
Password = {}
hostname = {}
status = {}
with open('Output.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvinput:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput)
    for item in reader:
        IP = item['IP']
        Host = item['Hostname']
        Username = item['Username']
        Password = item['Password']
        Type = item['Type']
        date = date.today()
        if 'Ping' in Type:
            print('This is ping device')
            try:
                ip = socket.gethostbyname(IP)
            except socket.error:
                pass
            name = socket.getfqdn(IP)
            data = name
            hostname = item['IP']
            response = subprocess.Popen(['ping.exe',hostname], stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
            response = response.decode()
            print(response)
            if 'bytes=32' in response:
                status = 'Up'
            elif 'destination host unreachable' in response:
                status = 'Unreachable'
            else:
                status = 'Down'
            if status == 'Down':
                ip = 'Not Found'
            with open('Ping-%s.txt' % (date), 'a', newline='') as f:
                f = csv.writer(f)
                f.writerow([hostname] + [data] + [status] + [ip])
##            with open('Ping-%s.csv' % (date), 'a', newline='') as csvoutput:
##                output = csv.writer(csvoutput)
##                output.writerow([hostname] + [data] + [status] + [ip])
        elif 'COR' in Type:
            # Create instance of SSHClient object
            remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
            # Add untrusted hosts
            remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            # Initiate SSH connection
            remote_conn_pre.connect(IP, username=Username, password=Password, port=22)
            print("SSH connection established to %s" % IP)
            # Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
            remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
            print("Interactive SSH session established")
            # Strip the initial router prompt
            terminal_output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
            # Send the router a command
            remote_conn.send("\n")
            remote_conn.send("terminal length 0\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            remote_conn.send("sh run\n")
            time.sleep(5)
            terminal_output = remote_conn.recv(9999999)
            print(terminal_output.decode())
            output1 = open('%s-%s.txt' % (Host,date), 'w')
            output1.write(terminal_output.decode())
            output1.close()
            remote_conn_pre.close()
        elif 'AP' in Type:
            # Create instance of SSHClient object
            remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
            # Add untrusted hosts
            remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            # Initiate SSH connection
            remote_conn_pre.connect(IP, username=Username, password=Password, port=22)
            print("SSH connection established to %s" % IP)
            # Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
            remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
            print("Interactive SSH session established")
            # Strip the initial router prompt
            terminal_output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
            # Send the router a command
            remote_conn.send("\n")
            remote_conn.send("sh run\n")
            time.sleep(10)
            terminal_output = remote_conn.recv(9999999)
            print(terminal_output.decode())
            output1 = open('%s-%s.txt' % (Host,date), 'w')
            output1.write(terminal_output.decode())
            output1.close()
            remote_conn_pre.close()
        elif 'EFW' in Type:
            # Create instance of SSHClient object
            remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
            # Add untrusted hosts
            remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            # Initiate SSH connection
            remote_conn_pre.connect(IP, username=Username, password=Password, port=22)
            print("SSH connection established to %s" % IP)
            # Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
            remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
            print("Interactive SSH session established")
            # Strip the initial router prompt
            terminal_output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
            # Send the router a command
            remote_conn.send("\n")
            remote_conn.send("show full-configuration\n")
            time.sleep(10)
            terminal_output = remote_conn.recv(9999999)
            print(terminal_output.decode())
            output1 = open('%s-%s.txt' % (Host,date), 'w')
            output1.write(terminal_output.decode())
            output1.close()
            remote_conn_pre.close()
        elif 'LUS' in Type:
            # Create instance of SSHClient object
            remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
            # Add untrusted hosts
            remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            # Initiate SSH connection
            remote_conn_pre.connect(IP, username=Username, password=Password, port=22)
            print("SSH connection established to %s" % IP)
            # Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
            remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
            print("Interactive SSH session established")
            # Strip the initial router prompt
            terminal_output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
            # Send the router a command
            remote_conn.send("\n")
            remote_conn.send("terminal datadump\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            remote_conn.send("sh run\n")
            time.sleep(10)
            terminal_output = remote_conn.recv(9999999)
            print(terminal_output.decode())
            output1 = open('%s-%s.txt' % (Host,date), 'w')
            output1.write(terminal_output.decode())
            output1.close()
            remote_conn_pre.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python users usually use a code writing style known as PEP-8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

There were some multiple things incorrect/out-of-place :
1. Don't import multiple packages in one line. (If they're not from same parent class)

```
import csv,subprocess,paramiko,time,socket
```

to :

```
import csv
import subprocess
import paramiko
import time
import socket
from datetime import date
```

2. Use space seperation after comma

```
['ping.exe',hostname]
```

to :

```
['ping.exe', hostname]
```

3. A empty line at the end of file.

And it does look good to add classes and functions but the most important reason to make a class is its reproducibility.
It all just matters how many times do you use this snippet.

There are many resources from where you can learn how to make a class and its functions

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/class

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Thanks, I have made those small changes.